# Как в symfony 4 с помощью createQueryBuilder сделать такой запрос?

Tags: symfony

Подскажите как в symfony 4 используя createQueryBuilder выполнить вот такой запрос?

> UPDATE tree SET left_key = left_key + 2, right_key = right_key + 2
>   WHERE left_key > 4;

Comment: используйте DQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$qb = $em->createQueryBuilder();

$qb->update('App:Tree', 'node');
$qb->set('node.left_key', 'node.left_key + :lk1');
$qb->set('node.right_key', 'node.right_key + :rk1');
$qb->where($qb->expr()->gt('node.left_key', ':lk2'));
$qb->setParameters([
    'lk1' => 2,
    'rk1' => 2,
    'lk2' => 4
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

$query = $em->createQuery(
     'UPDATE App:Tree t
      SET t.left_key = t.left_key + 2, t.right_key = t.right_key + 2
      WHERE t.left_key > 4'
);
```